# Logistic regression by TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, error-handling, logistic-regression

I'm a beginner of TensorFlow. I'd like to try logistic regression by the following code on TensorFlow. But I couldn't know how I should deal with the Error. I don't have confidence about my code at all.. If it has anything wrong, please give me some advice.

```
x_data=[2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6]
y_data=[1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]
b = tf.Variable([1.0])
a = tf.Variable([1.0])
eta = a + b * x_data
p = 1/(1+tf.math.exp(-eta))
xxx = -tf.reduce_sum((y_data * tf.log(p) + (1 - y_data) * tf.log(1 - p)))

#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the error you need to convert the inputs `x_data` & `y_data` to a [TensorFlow tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) as follows:

```
x_data=tf.constant([2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6], dtype='float32')
y_data=tf.constant([1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0], dtype='float32')
```

Below is a screenshot of the result `xxx`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much about your answer! and link too. I got it.

Comment: Glad to help :)